# Gzipping file using Ajax Minfy tool

Tags: javascript, ajax

I was wondering if it's possible to do G Zip also using Ajax Minfy tool.When running the command line tool during conversion it shows how much % it compresses and how much can be G Zipped but it does not actually G Zip it only does the compression ..So is it possible to G Zip using this tool http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gzip compression should be done by the server, as the server knows whether the client is able to decompress the data. If properly configured the webserver will handle it transparently for you.

In lighttpd you can enable compression like this:

```
server.modules += ( "mod_compress" )

compress.cache-dir = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/" # change this as you want
compress.filetype = ( 
    "application/x-javascript",
    "application/javascript",
    "text/javascript",
    "text/css",
    "text/html",
    "text/plain"
)
```

for further information see [ModCompress in the lighttpd manual](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModCompress).

Comment: so the Ajax Minfy tool does not do this but I can use your above script to do it explicitly if I want..Do you know the script for IIS 7

Comment: @user505210 It does not handle it for you. You can add the lines above to your lighttpd.conf to enable compression (if you are using lighttpd obviously).  Make sure to clean the cache folder properly, this is not done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

gzip-ing is done at the server side, this can be done in a number of ways:

1. Automatically using your server software (see the documentation for your web server software).
2. Using a server side script, for example the PHP one below:

   ```
   <?php    
       header("Content-Encoding: gzip");
       echo gzencode($file_contents, 9);
   ?>
   ```

This PHP example first sets the gzip content encoding header, this instructs the browser to decompress the response and then outputs the encoded file contents (using a high compression level set at 9). For more info see the [PHP documentation on gzip](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzencode.php).

Comment: gzip compression with `level = 9` without caching is very bad.

Comment: @TimWolla you can add the caching headers in PHP or change the gzip level. e.g. "header("Cache-Control: max-age=2592000");" for 30 days.